# Switching my apps install behaviour with android:installLocation

Tags: installation, google-play-services, android-manifest

My users get update errors in GooglePlay with errors "907" and "963" and I believe it is because the app is installed on external sdcard.

So I just think to prevent this I could change the install behaviour of my app be changing the android:installLocation from "auto" to "internalOnly".

Now I am not sure what happens to all already installed apps located on the external memory card, when they update to a version configured to "internalOnly".

Is there any issue, risk that the install will fail ?

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error 907 is similar to Android error 963 where installation or update is cancelled right after the download bar reaches completion. If you have already tried re-installing after a reboot and you're still getting this error, here is how you can fix the error:

- Clear Cache and Data.
- Update Google Play Store - check if your Google Play Store is the latest version. 
  *Unmount SD card before install

You may check this forum for more solution offered by community: http://valuestuffz.blogspot.com/2015/06/how-to-fix-error-907-in-google-play.html

For your question, 'now I am not sure what happens to all already installed apps located on the external memory card, when they update to a version configured to "internalOnly"?

It depends on your version of Android.  [Android 6.0 Marshmallow](http://www.howtogeek.com/114667/how-to-install-android-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-move-almost-any-app-to-the-sd-card/) lets your 'adopt' your SD card. Some pre-Marshmallow devices may let you move apps manually, but only if the developer allows it. If you want more flexibility than either of these options offer, you can root your phone and use an app called Link2SD to make it happen.

Additionally, when you adopt your SD card as internal storage, you cannot remove the SD card from the device without affecting the functionality of your device and the SD card is not usable in any other device.